# wordpress 6.4.2 gutenberg custom block array attributes saving problem?

Tags: block-editor

this save code getting error for new wordpress 6.4.2  version this save code dont working for but if i use 6.0.0 version wp then it will working fine no problem

```
attributes: {
    tabs: {
      type: 'array',
      default: [
        { tabLabel: 'Tab 1', tabContent: 'Content for Tab 1' }
      ],
    },   }, edit: ({ attributes, setAttributes }) => {
    const { tabs } = attributes;
    const updateTabContent = (value, tabIndex) => {
      const updatedTabs = [...tabs];
      updatedTabs[tabIndex].tabContent = value;
      setAttributes({ tabs: updatedTabs });
    };
    return (
      <div className="my-custom-block">
        {tabs.map((tab, tabIndex) => (
          <div key={tabIndex}>
            <RichText
              tagName="h6"
              value={tab.tabLabel}
              onChange={(value) => updateTabLabel(value, tabIndex)}
              placeholder="Tab Label..."
            />
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
    );   }, save: ({ attributes }) => {
    const { tabs } = attributes;
    return (
      <div className="my-custom-block">
        {tabs.map((tab, tabIndex) => (
          <div key={tabIndex}>
            <h6>{tab.tabLabel}</h6>
            <div>{tab.tabContent}</div>
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
    );   },
```

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: Block validation: Block validation failed for `blogee-accordion-block/blogee-accordion
Content generated by `save` function:

<div class="wp-block-blogee-accordion-block-blogee-accordion"></div>

Content retrieved from post body:

<div class="wp-block-blogee-accordion-block-blogee-accordion"><div><p>Tab</p></div><div><p>Tab 2</p></div></div>
this the error in console

Comment: Could you edit that into the question instead? It would be easier to read.

Comment: I think it's saying that the two "Content generated by" outputs should be the same. You can see that your save function output doesn't contain the Tab paragraphs.

Comment: what should i do to solving this problem ?

Comment: I'd debug the edit and save functions here: trace out the inputs and outputs of the edit function, and try and spot what's going wrong.

Comment: Recent versions of WP have deprecated some components. I would try removing the `<RichText>` and if that resolves the error, you can replace it with `<InnerBlocks>` and just use a Core Heading block instead.